# Public key and private key are not found in Keychain access

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I think I accidentaly deleted public and private keys from Keychain Access-> login -> keys. Now when I generate new certificates, I am not seeing these keys. May I know how to restore or re download these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deleted the private key (and don't have a backup), then you need to login to your Apple Developer account, go to provisioning portal, revoke the current developer or distribution key and follow the steps to create new ones.

**Note: You will have to re-download any app provisioning profiles you may have also created to use the new private key**